# Getting specific user input characters in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, barcode-scanner

I'm a beginner and have just started exploring Tkinter and python programming. I came across a Tkinter program template which I would like to test some features on. Currently, this section allows user to input the ID values, and from the DB, the varchar is set to 45. I have a barcode reader in which when I scan produces a long output like "ID:ffffff100.....n SN:SK1980....n". Are there any way for me to only accept the values from "ffffff100....n" Only ? So that when I scan and ADD, it only inserts from "fff till n(excluding ID: and SN:SK19..n) ? What choices do I have?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJGX5.png) I have attached some codes segment which I believe is the relevant segment and images for your reference. Thanks.

```
#Entry Type: Register New Asset
elif (choices == "Register New Asset"):
    test1 = Check(temp_Entry.get(), gps_Entry.get(), current_Entry.get())
    if (test1 == "TRUE"):
        command = ("SELECT `Asset ID` FROM `Asset IDs` WHERE `Asset ID` = %s")
        mycursor.execute(command, (ID_Box.get(), ))
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
        
        if len(results) == 0:
            command = ("INSERT INTO `Asset IDs` (`Asset ID`) VALUES (%s)")
            mycursor.execute(command, (ID_Box.get(), ))
            connection.commit()
            
        command = ("SELECT `Device EUI` FROM `Temp/Hum Sensors` WHERE `Device EUI` = %s")
        mycursor.execute(command, (temp_Entry.get(), ))
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
        
        if len(results) == 0:
            command = ("INSERT INTO `Temp/Hum Sensors` (`Device EUI`) VALUES (%s)")
            mycursor.execute(command, (temp_Entry.get(), ))
            connection.commit()

        command = ("SELECT `Device EUI` FROM `GPS Sensors` WHERE `Device EUI` = %s")
        mycursor.execute(command, (gps_Entry.get(), ))
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
            
        if len(results) == 0:
            command = ("INSERT INTO `GPS Sensors` (`Device EUI`) VALUES (%s)")
            mycursor.execute(command, (gps_Entry.get(), ))
            connection.commit()
        
        command = ("SELECT `Device EUI` FROM `Current Sensors` WHERE `Device EUI` = %s")
        mycursor.execute(command, (current_Entry.get(), ))
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
            
        if len(results) == 0:
            command = ("INSERT INTO `Current Sensors` (`Device EUI`) VALUES (%s)")
            mycursor.execute(command, (current_Entry.get(), ))
            connection.commit()
        
        command = ("INSERT INTO `Inventory` (`Asset ID`, `Equipment Type`, `Temp/Hum EUI`, `GPS EUI`, `Current EUI`, `Status`, `Remarks`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
        val = (ID_Box.get(), asset_Box.get(), temp_Entry.get(), gps_Entry.get(), current_Entry.get(), status_Entry.get(), remarks_Entry.get())
        mycursor.execute(command, val)
        connection.commit()

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Register New Asset", "Successfully registered!")
        
        clear_fields([asset_Box, ID_Box, temp_Entry, gps_Entry, current_Entry, name_Entry, company_Entry, email_Entry, contact_Entry, issue_Entry, return_Entry, status_Entry, remarks_Entry, issuehours, issueminutes, issuedays, returnhours, returnminutes, returndays])
        entry_Box.configure(state="normal")
        entry_Box.delete(0, "end")
        entry_Box.insert(0, "Select the following")
        entry_Box.configure(state="readonly")
        entry_Box.focus()

        addbutton.configure(state="disable")
    else:
        valueErrorMessage = "Invalid input for " + test1 
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", valueErrorMessage)

command = "SELECT `Asset ID` from `Inventory`"
mycursor.execute(command)
results = mycursor.fetchall()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnckE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGCdO.png)

Comment: Sorry for the wrong picture order as this is my first post. Please refer to the last image for the GUI(1st), first and second image for the MYSQL DB. Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard about `slicing`?

Comment: Use `.split(' ')[0].split(':')[-1]` to extract the required part from the barcode reader result.

Comment: @acw1668 Where do I need to paste this ?

Comment: I can't tell you where because I don't know your application design.

Comment: @acw1668 is it here: if len(results) == 0: ? because the next line is to insert the data into database right ?

Comment: I don't think so.  It may be before  the `SELECT` statement as you want to check whether it exists in the table.

Comment: @acw1668 but doesn't connection.commit() actually inserts the values into the table ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it yourself and see whether it works the way you want?